# Can I implement clipping using SFML 2.1 2d drawing API?

Tags: c#, c++, sfml

I am implementing a simplistic GUI library for a game.

My solution uses SFML 2.1 2d API.

As you can imagine, the ui elements are organized in a hierarchical structure. Children are expected to render within the bounds of their parents.

I could live with the need to trust children to render outside their parent. However, to implement scrolling in a simple manner, I'd like to clip whatever children render.

Is there a way to achieve this using the SFML 2d api ?

For now, I could only come up with drawing to a texture and use that texture for a shape or sprite. I am concerned with performance (even though, the texture would only be regenerated when UI content changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this features isn't yet implemented, but you're not the only one waiting for it, see the [first issue](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/issues/1) ever created on SFML's GitHub issue tracker.

In the meantime the only way is to either use OpenGL directly or via a `sf::RenderTexture`.

Comment: I chose sfml to stay away from opengl. Sosf::RenterTexture is the way to go for me. However, managing the lifetime of the temporary texture is a hassle.

Comment: @TiMoch just make sure to keep the texture around for as long as you want to draw things and at best, reuse what you have as much as possible. ;)